The chat filter by "relevance" or "stars" gets reset to "newest" upon changing the query
When you sort chat search by relevance or stars from those buttons:



And then change the query to something else (just one change is enough), it gets reset to the "newest" filter.
I would prefer that the sorting preference is kept upon changing the query.

Note, this also applies to site search which don't remember the sorting. Not sure it can be considered a bug, as this is how the system works from the very beginning, and as they meant it to work.
